# retrieve database file update form on button click in flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to make an html page and flask route that will open a database update form when i press a button, but so far I only get an error saying the url doesn't exist or the server overloaded. Here is what I have:

Route:

```py
@app.route('/python_forum')
def python_forum():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/python.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT rank, codename, name, actors, description FROM pythonpage Order By rank"
    c.execute(sql)
    pythonforum = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        tup = (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4])
        pythonforum.append(tup)
    conn.close()
    return render_template('pythonforum.html', pythonforum=pythonforum)

@app.route('/addform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addform():
  if request.method == 'GET':
      '''conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/python.db")
      f = conn.cursor()
      sql = "SELECT rank, codename, name, actors, description FROM pythonpage Order By rank"
      f.execute(sql)
      r, c, n, a, d = "", "", "", "", ""
      for row in f.fetchall():
          if int(addpythoncode) == int(row[0]):
              r, c, n, a, d = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]
      conn.close()'''
      return render_template('addpython.html')
  elif request.method == 'POST':
      conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/python.db")
      sql = "Insert into pythonpage ('codename', 'name', 'description') values('" + \
          request.form['name'] + "', "
      sql = sql + "'" + request.form['codename'] + "', "
      sql = sql + "'" + request.form['description'] + "') "
      conn.execute(sql)
      conn.commit()
      return render_template('pythonforum.html')

@app.route('/pythoncode')
def pythoncode():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/python.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT description FROM pythonpage Order By description"
    c.execute(sql)
    pycodeforum = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        tup = (row[0])
        pycodeforum.append(tup)
    conn.close()
    return render_template('updatepython.html', pycodeforum=pycodeforum)
```

html code form "addpythoncode":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link data-require="bootstrap@4.1.3" data-semver="4.1.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@4.1.3" data-semver="4.1.3" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align='center'>Add Python Code</h1>
<table width="90%">
 <form method="POST">
 <tr>
     <td>Code name</td>
     <td><input type=text name="codename" placeholder="name your code" value='{{c}}' size=40 /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td><input type=text name=name placeholder="enter your name" value='{{n}}' size=50 /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Description</td>
     <td><textarea name='description' placeholder="enter your code" rows=5 cols=50>{{d}}</textarea></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
       <tr>
     <td><input type=hidden name=rank value={{r}} /></td>
     <td><input type=submit value='submit' class='btn btn-primary' /></td>
 </tr>
 </form>
 </table><br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='/python_forum'>Back Home</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

pythonforum:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}

</style>
<style>

.button {
  background-color: #1E90FF; /* Blue */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 87%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;

}

.button1 {padding: 10px 24px;}
.button1 {border-radius: 8px;}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    a.nounderline {text-decoration: none; }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    a.nounderline {text-decoration: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Python Forum</h1>
<br/>
<button type="submit" style="float: right;" class="button button1"><a href="/addform"</>Add code</button>
<table width="90%">
    <br/>
   {% for x in pythonforum:  %}
   <tr>
        <td width=20%><a href='/pythoncode' >{{ x[1] }}</a></td>
        <td width=20%> {{ x[2] }} </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

What this is doing is trying to take a row from the .db file that already exists and edit it. i want to make a form that will add a new row to the db file. I can figure out the html form, but I can't figure out how to make a route that will allow the user to go to the form when pressing a button.

Comment: Please provide more information from your debugging console.

Comment: What the problem is is that I have essentially made a code that will update a current entry in the .db rather than make a new entry. Is it possible to provide me with a way to do this?

Comment: It seems like your code have a different problem. First try to solve that. The update query seems just ok. If you ran your code from terminal (like running it with flask command), see what error message is dispaled when you reload the page.

Comment: So What this is doing is trying to take a row from the .db file that already exists and eidt it. i want to make a form that will add a new row to the db file.

Comment: The logic is similar with update but uses different sql command. If you have problem writing a sql query, provide db structure at least (code for initializing db).

Comment: I am pretty new to coding. how exactly do i go about this?

Comment: Seems like you didn't provide the complete code. Consider editing your code and providing more information. Look for a code containing syntax like `create table ...`

Comment: so i can figure out the html form, but I can't figure out how to make a route that will allow the user to go to the form when pressing a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new route for adding a row to the table you can edit your code or add another route like this:

```py
@app.route('/addform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addform():
  if request.method == 'GET':
      conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/python.db")
      c = conn.cursor()
      sql = "SELECT rank, title, genre, actors, description FROM IMDB Order By rank"
      c.execute(sql)
      r, t, g, a, de = "", "", "", "", ""
      for row in c.fetchall():
          if int(addpythoncode) == int(row[0]):
              r, t, g, a, de = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]
      conn.close()
      return render_template('addpython.html', addpythoncode=addpythoncode, r=r, t=t, g=g, a=a, de=de)
  elif request.method == 'POST':
      conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/python.db")
      sql = "Insert into IMDB (title, director, actors, description) values(" + \
          request.form['genre'] + "', "
      sql = sql + request.form['title'] + ", "
      sql = sql + request.form['director'] + ", "
      sql = sql + request.form['actors'] + ", "
      sql = sql + request.form['description'] + ") "
      conn.execute(sql)
      conn.commit()
      return render_template('pythonforum.html')
```

The elif part of the code is responsible for adding a new row to the table. You didn't provide any structure for the database, so I assumed the structure based on update query.

You can add this function to the python code and make sure that corresponding template form files are present (they usually are identical to update forms). Change your html code so that it aims to `/addform` location.

As a side note, It's not a good practice to use sqlite directly, and get form params and build the query without any processing as this might lead to sql injection. Try using sqlalchemy instead.

Comment: I am putting an updated version of the addpythoncode as well as the forum home page in the original post. I am most likely missing something, but it keeps telling me the same message.

Comment: I also put the updated route on there as well. I changed the name of the table and some attributes which is why i edited the route code you put above

Comment: This is what I get when I check the error log:    File "/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/flask_app.py", line 179, in addform
    for row in c.fetchall():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Comment: You have changed your code. You executed c variable and assigned an empty string to it so that c.fetchall won't work! try changing c variable that comes afterward or change c name in `c = conn.cursor()`. You have multiple variables with same names.

Comment: That fixed it, but now it is telling me: Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: Try changing `method=post` to `method="POST"`

Comment: I figured out the problem. So what happens now is the update form appends to the .db file. The python_forum route displays the name of the code and the uploader name while another route is supposed to show the description, but right now it only shows the first letter of the description. I will include the once again updated code above